# JS как вывести выбранноe значение из select'a в span

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Как вывести выбранный option из select'a в блок span

Но так же значение должно браться из data-val

Вот мой пример работы выводит в input, а мне нужно просто html в span

```js
$('select.but').on('click', function() {
    $('#my_field4').val( $(this).val() );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="" style="padding-top:20px">
<select class="but">
  <option data-val="a">a</option>
  <option data-val="b">b</option>
  <option data-val="c">c</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="my_field4" value="">
<span id="my_field4"> </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ну если совсем не заморачиваться.
У тебя 2 элемента с одним ID. Такого быть не должно.

```
$('select.but').on('click', function() {
    $('#my_field4').val( $(this).val() );
    $('.my_field4_span').text( $(this).val() );

});

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="" style="padding-top:20px">
<select class="but">
  <option data-val="a">a</option>
  <option data-val="b">b</option>
  <option data-val="c">c</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="my_field4" value="">
<span class="my_field4_span"> </span>
</div>
```

Comment: до данная функция, не берет значения из data-val